# Entity Framework 6 Where Clause Builder Class

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, repository-pattern

I created a class to help build a collection of Where clauses and then a method which applies them when building the query using a repository pattern in an Entity Framework 6 code-first project. The Equal, NotEqual and Contains part of the Apply method all work just fine.

My question or issue is how do I apply a Greater Than and Less Than clause to the query with this type of class implementation? I have them stubbed in below of how it would typically be coded for a Linq query but there is obviously errors on "a" and the field value. I do have a TProperty on class instantiation that should be able to check and use to cast the FieldValue since you can't use operator '>' or '<' with certain data types. So I believe the 'a' portion of the expression is the issue, no idea what to use here??

Here is the class which accepts a generic object type and generic property type. It has a constructor which is used to create new instances and hold several properties in storage. The list is then passed to a repository class which loops through them and calls the ApplyWhere method to apply to query.

```
public class WhereClause<T, TProperty> : IWhereClause<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private string FieldName { get; set; }
    private object FieldValue { get; set; }
    private Enums.WhereOperation WhereOperation { get; set; }

    public WhereClause(string fieldName, object fieldValue, Enums.WhereOperation whereOperation)
    {
        this.FieldName = fieldName;
        this.FieldValue = fieldValue;
        this.WhereOperation = whereOperation;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> ApplyWhere(IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        switch ((int)this.WhereOperation)
        {
            case (int)Enums.WhereOperation.Equal:
                return query.WhereEqual(this.FieldName, this.FieldValue);

            case (int)Enums.WhereOperation.NotEqual:
                return query.WhereNotEqual(this.FieldName, this.FieldValue);

            case (int)Enums.WhereOperation.Contains:
                return query.WhereContains(this.FieldName, this.FieldValue);

           **case (int)Enums.WhereOperation.GreaterThan:
                return query.Where(a => a > this.FieldValue);
            case (int)Enums.WhereOperation.LessThan:
                return query.Where(a => a < this.FieldValue);**
        }
        return query;
    }
}
```

Here is how I build the list of Where clauses to pass to the repository:

```
IWhereClause<Schema.Model.Product>[] whereClause = new IWhereClause<Schema.Model.Product>[1];
whereClause[0] = new WhereClause<Schema.Model.Product, string>("SKU", "BKL-14244", Enums.WhereOperation.Equal);
```

Here is a snippet inside the repository Select method which builds the where clauses for the IQueryable query:

```
if (whereClause != null) 
{
    whereClause.ToList().ForEach(one =>
    {
         query = one.ApplyWhere(query);
    });
}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) of [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx).

Comment: please show the WhereNotEqual and WhereContains methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. As you stated, it was complicated so I ended up creating Expressions of type Expression> for any search parameter that was not null. Not entirely generic but good enough, allowed me to drill down into any EF child navigation property.

Then using an Expression Visitor extension class/method, I combined multiple expressions together using And/Or operators. Then finally applied the dynamically built expression list to the IQueryable query and voila, my filtered results.

Comment: make sure to use the new Log functionality to check what the sql query look like.

Answer (score 1):

You are about to re-invent the wheel.  (Minus a few spokes? )

If you are serious about doing "dynamic linq".
Then i suggest you embrace it.   Use one of several ways to build a predicate at runtime.

1. The "best" string based tool i have seen is [Dynamic linq](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/)
   Discussed here. [scott GUs blog on dynamic linq - the string version](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)
2. The most powerful way [Expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882637.aspx)
   This is harder to do if you are unfamiliar with expression trees.
   But you can build the predicate required.
3. there are other approaches. Sorry I cant say too much about them. Have never used them.
   they will have some similarity to 1 and/or 2.
   eg  [Predicate builder.  helps add OR and AND dynamically.](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)
   But isnt powerful enough to help in you scenario.
4. Or partial custom solutions as you are attempting.

Your example is  currently comparing the whole type. So needs some work.
But im suggesting you dont try and continue down the path you are on.

> .Where(a => a < this.FieldValue)

If You wish to research the topic. [Search for Dynamic Linq in C#](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=dynamic%20linq%20C%23)

Comment: Unfortunately none of this is news and not much help. #2 and #4 are both options but looking for some code or good shove in the right direction. And you don't explain why #4 is not recommended, just that I shouldn't continue down this path. There are built in Equal and NotEqual functions, seems a Greater Than shouldn't be that difficult, everything is working great with my implemented pattern accept this issue.

Comment: I mentioned why it wasnt working .Where(a => a < this.FieldValue)   You compare the whole type.   This.Field < This.FieldValue ???  And i did mention i thought you were re-inventing a wheel.  Your partial solution 4 is also listed as an option.

Comment: Your suggestion of query.Where(a => this.FieldName < this.FieldValue) does not work. FieldName is a string, FieldValue is object. Error: Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'object'. And I know my partial solution (#4) is an option, this is what I'm trying to get a completed solution for.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt trying to suggest you code Where(a => this.FieldName < this.FieldValue) .   I added ??? to ask you wanted to compare Fields and not objects.   But as you have since discovered. Simple object < string  You now have the issue of build the predicate with types and not objects. since the generic type <T> isnt constrained beyond new Class

Comment: I will add I comment to explain why what you are trying will be hard

Comment: please add your  query.WhereNotEqual and whereContains methods